# Comparing two dates with a given format

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to compare two dates using javascript with ExtJS 4.

```
var d= Ext.Date.parse("03/21/2012", "m/d/Y");
var comp= new Date();

if (d< comp) {
    console.log("date value provided is larger" );
} else {
    console.log("date value provided is less" );
}
```

When running the above example, the result I get is "date value provided is less". However, when I change the value of `d` to a future date `12/21/2012`, I still get the message "date value provided is less".

I think this is because I need to format the `var comp= new Date();` value so it can do the calculation.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Ext.Date.parse("03/21/2012", "m/d/Y") < new Date()` gives `true`. Tested in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variables `d` and `comp` are objects. They are instances of `Date`.

EDIT: Date objects can be compared using `<` operator in JavaScript. Your code looks fine, it works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpfahler/F6wuX/).

```
var d = Ext.Date.parse("03/21/2012", "m/d/Y");
var comp = new Date();

if (d < comp) {
    console.log("date value provided is larger" );
} else {
    console.log("date value provided is less" );
}
```

Thanks for clarifying the date comparison in the comments.

Comment: 'else' block could also indicate Dates are equal?

Comment: Logic will not work if the dates are equal since two objects in javascript are never the same. So the text "date value provided is less" would be wrong.